# NLog ignores the config file

Tags: c#, logging, nlog, .net-4.8

For some reason, the NLog ignores the config file. I have an `NLog.config` file with `Build Action: Content` and `Copy to Output Directory: Copy always`.

Here is the config file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <targets>
    <target name="default" xsi:type="Console" />
    <target name="dump" xsi:type="File" filename="./dump.log">
      <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="true">
      </layout>
    </target>
  </targets>

  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <logger name="DumpLogger" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="dump" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="dump" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

I have this code:

```
var logger = LogManager.GetLogger("DumpLogger");
logger.Trace("Try Trace"); // ignored
logger.Info("Try Info"); // writes to console
```

I also tried to add an explicit NLog config before the `GetLogger` call:

```
LogManager.LoadConfiguration(@"C:\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\bin\x64\Debug\NLog.config");
```

But I get the same result.

Why NLog ignore my config file?

Comment: Why do you think it's ignored? Because you can't find the log file?

Comment: No, because the `minLevel` is `Trace` while `Trace` log is being ignored (output only Debug and above) and since The `DumpLogger` should write to file but the log goes to the console.
The file is not created at all, but this is not the only symptom.

Comment: The default file name for the Nlog file name should be `<ExecutableName>.nlog`, so copy NLog.Config as `MyApplication.exe.nlog` to the bin directory.

Comment: Same behavior. Print to console and ignores Trace...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some correction, the code you provided work pretty well:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <targets>
    <target name="default" xsi:type="Console" />
    <target name="dump" xsi:type="File" filename="./dump.log">
      <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="true">
        <!-- Add something in the json entries -->
        <attribute name="timestamp" layout="${date:universalTime=true:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss,fff}" />
        <attribute name="level" layout="${level}"/>
        <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
      </layout>
    </target>
  </targets>

  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <logger name="DumpLogger" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="dump" />
    <!-- Use default here instead of dump -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="default" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

And:

```csharp
using NLog;

namespace NLogTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var logger = LogManager.GetLogger("DumpLogger");
            logger.Trace("Try Trace");
            logger.Info("Try Info");

        }
    }
}
```

Content of `dump.log`:

```json
{ "timestamp": "2021-10-21 11:26:34,672", "level": "Trace", "message": "Try Trace" }
{ "timestamp": "2021-10-21 11:26:34,697", "level": "Info", "message": "Try Info" }
```

Console output:

```
2021-10-21 13:13:27.8513|TRACE|DumpLogger|Try Trace
2021-10-21 13:13:27.8815|INFO|DumpLogger|Try Info
```

Comment: But shouldn't it load the config file automatically? Anyway, it is not working either (same results)

Comment: @nrofis indeed auto-loading of the configuration works fine

Comment: I don't understand this. This configuration still not working for me. I put it in `NLog.config` and `ConsoleApplication1.exe.nlog` in the bin folder. Nothing.

Comment: About the default, This is my intent, but it was just for testing - no console output at all.

Comment: When you say the `bin folder` it's the `bin/debug/..` folder ? next to the executable ?

Comment: Sure. Same folder as the EXE. `...\ConsoleApplication1\bin\x64\Debug\NLog.config`

Comment: Notice the documentations says `LogFactory instance for fluent interface`, so the return value is the active LogFactory. So this answers should be updated to reflect that. Notice also that NLog will attempt to automatically load Nlog.config from [several locations](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#configuration-file-locations).